# How do I surround different blocks of code with the same repeating block of code?

Tags: java

For instance:

```
public void foo(string something, Boolean flag, Object obj){
  try{
    if(flag){
       //some code
    }
 } catch(Exception e) {
     // handle exception
 }
}

public void doo(string something, Boolean flag){
  try{
    if(flag){
       //different code
    }
 } catch(Exception e) {
     // handle exception
 }
}

public void roo(string something, Boolean flag, Integer id){
  try{
    if(flag){
       //a bit of code
    }
 } catch(Exception e) {
     // handle exception
 }
}
```

My question is, is there any way to not have all the repeating code in every function (e.g. the try-catch blocks and the ifs)? It would really clear up my project and would help me focus on the important code.

Comment: You may want to research aspects here. Essentially decorate any given method invocation with before, after or around advice so that repetitive, out-of-scope code doesn't get in the way. Since you're using Spring, you're in luck as there is a specific Spring AOP library for that.

Comment: Is handling the exception the same in all cases?

Comment: So in your example you have all the same variables in which case I can't see why you would need 3 different methods, is this how the actual project is?

Comment: What is the difference between the functions?  Is it just the "some code"  bit?

Comment: Handling the exceptions is the same in every case. Yes.

Comment: I'll edit so it will look more like the project I'm working on.

Comment: what about passing executable code?

Comment: Where is `something` used? In the different pieces of code, or in exception handling?

Answer (score 4):

What about passing a `Runnable` to a new method that catch exceptions?

```
public void foo(String something, Boolean flag, Object obj) {
    runSafe(something, flag, () => /*some code capturing obj*/);
}

public void doo(String something, Boolean flag) {
    runSafe(something, flag, () => /*different code*/);
}

public void roo(String something, Boolean flag, Integer id) {
    runSafe(something, flag, () => /*some code capturing id*/);
}

private void runSafe(string something, Boolean flag, Runnable r) {
    try {
        if (flag) {
            r.run();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

However, passing a boolean saying whether or not to execute code looks wrong to me. Why don't you use some sort of null-object implementation of these methods (doing nothing) instead of passing false?

Comment: `Runnable` can't throw a checked exception. Don't know whether the OP's exception is checked...

Comment: @slim Good point, in that case, `Callable<Void>` could be used instead, or even better, a suitable specific user-defined functional interface to implement the same idea.

Comment: What about if the functions foo/doo/roo aren't void functions? Is runnable what I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You can surround with try-catch the call of this methods. If you need a unique response for each Exception, you can either create an object that extends Exception, or just use the Exception constructor with a string message.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want to hear but you may want to consider cutting down on your try/catch blocks.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145941/efficient-try-catch-block-usage