# How do I surround different blocks of code with the same repeating block of code? While being able to return different values

Tags: java, spring

For instance:

```
public Object foo(string something, Boolean flag, Object obj){
  try{
    if(flag){
       //some code
    }
 } catch(Exception e) {
     // handle exception
 }
}

public Object doo(string something, Boolean flag){
  try{
    if(flag){
       //different code
    }
 } catch(Exception e) {
     // handle exception
 }
}

public Object roo(string something, Boolean flag, Integer id){
  try{
    if(flag){
       //a bit of code
    }
 } catch(Exception e) {
     // handle exception
 }
}
```

My question is, is there any way to not have all the repeating code in every function (e.g. the try-catch blocks and the ifs)? It would really clear up my project and would help me focus on the important code.

I asked this question already about void functions and noticed that the proposed solution (using a runnable) did not work on functions with return types other than null. Is there a different way to implement this?

Link to my previous (and very related) question: [How do I surround different blocks of code with the same repeating block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406899/how-do-i-surround-different-blocks-of-code-with-the-same-repeating-block-of-code)

Answer (score 0):

When you need a return value, you can use a Callable instead of a Runnable. I have modified the example Joffrey gave in the other thread:

```
class CallableExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CallableExample ce = new CallableExample();
        System.out.println(ce.foo("", true, ""));
        System.out.println(ce.doo("", true));
        System.out.println(ce.roo("", true, 1));
    }

    public Object foo(String something, Boolean flag, Object obj) {
        return runCallable(something, flag, new Callable() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                return "foo";
            }
        });
    }

    public Object doo(String something, Boolean flag) {
        return runCallable(something, flag, new Callable() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                return "doo";
            }
        });
    }

    public Object roo(String something, Boolean flag, Integer id) {
        return runCallable(something, flag, new Callable() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                return "roo";
            }
        });
    }

    private Object runCallable(String something, Boolean flag, Callable c) {
        Object result = null;
        try {
            if (flag) {
                result = c.call();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Template Method design pattern  and the Execute Around idiom. However, if you find yourself often writing code that catches exceptions, that is a design Smell: ask yourself why you are doing that, and if it is really  necessary. Often letting exceptions propagate  to the calling context is better.

Answer (score 0):

Why use same code in different methods, instead write a single function for same set of code with if-else-if logic with try catch and minimise your code
for instance:

```
public Object foo(string something, Boolean flag, Object obj) {
    try {
       //convert the object type to primitive type data like int, String or any
       if(flag) {
          //your code 
       }
    catch(Exception ex) {
       //your code
    }
    //return the object;
}
```

convert Object type data to primitive type and use it accordingly
use if else if logic